# delete button on image upload with preview

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select multiple images and give those images a button so that user can delete the image as well. I'm able to do the preview of the image but I'm not able to delete the image after preview.

This is my javascript code

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

And this is my HTML code where id=list is the area where images are shown as thumbnails:

```
<div class="file-upload">
    <div class="file-select">
        <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">Choose Image</div>
        <div class="file-select-name" id="noFile"></div>
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 xol-sm-12">
    <output id="list"></output>
</div>
```

How to insert delete option with every image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this https://jsfiddle.net/dp722j27/10/

you can have a delete method like this

```
function deleteImage() { 
    var index = Array.from(document.getElementById('list').children).indexOf(event.target.parentNode)
    document.querySelector("#list").removeChild( document.querySelectorAll('#list span')[index]);
    totalFiles.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(totalFiles)
}
```

and your render method like

```
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = ['<img width=100 class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                    '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>', "<button onclick='deleteImage()'>delete</button>"].join('');

  document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
```

you can store the values in an array and handle it like

Comment: it is just deleting the space not the count of images

Comment: @juhi I think you forgot to mention that in your question, I will update my answer now

Comment: @juhi where are you adding those images ?

Comment: it is working but i want the position of the button to be on the image so that it get activated when someone hover on the image

Comment: you can have it, with the help of CSS, check this https://jsfiddle.net/dp722j27/11/

Answer (score 0):

My Js Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

          // Only process image files.
          if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
          }

          var reader = new FileReader();

          // Closure to capture the file information.
          reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
              // Render thumbnail.
              var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.innerHTML = ['<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 xol-sm-3" id="butt"><div class="container1"><img class="thumb img-responsive" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" /><div class="overlay"><div class="text"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:40px;color:#fff;"></i></div></div></div></div>'].join('');
              document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
          })(f);

          // Read in the image file as a data URL.
          reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
      }

      document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);


      $('#list').on('click', '#butt',function () {
              $(this).parent('span').remove();

      //this is not working...
      var i = array.indexOf($(this));
      if(i != -1) {
          array.splice(i, 1);
      }
      // tried this too:
      //$(this).parent('span').splice( 1, 1 );

      count--;
      });
});
```

My Html Code:

```
 <div class="row bgcolor">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-16 col-xs-12 xol-sm-12">
                                <div class="file-upload">
                                    <div class="file-select">
                                        <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">Choose Images
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 xol-sm-12">
                                <output id="list">  

                                </output>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

my css code:

```
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 92%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -14px;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: #000;
}
.overlay1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -14px;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 3;
  transition: .5s ease;
/*      background-color: #000;*/
}
.container1:hover .overlay1 {
 opacity: 0.2;
}


.container1:hover .overlay {
 opacity: 0.2;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is the correct answer!!!

Thank you for the help